# Automatically build hyperlinks to the content of chapters

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013

I'm creating some document in Microsoft Word, I was wondering if it was possible to have Word generate some hyperlinks under the **heading 1 (chapter title)** to all **heading 2 (sub chapters)** that are before next **heading 1 (new chapter)** for example:

```
Heading 1
 *hyperlink heading 2-1
 *hyperlink to heading 2-2
  .
  .
  content of hedings 2-1,2-2
  .
  .
 Heading 1-2
   *hyperlink heading 2-1
```

Is it possible to do so from style formater? or there are other toools to recive such result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a Table of Contents (TOC) field, but you will need to select the text of each chapter and insert a bookmark. IMO the alternative to using a TOC would be to insert and maintain individual hyperlink fields.

If you insert a Table of Contents, then use Alt-F9 to toggle field code display, you should see something like

```
{ TOC \o "1-3" \h \z \u }
```

You can look up what it all means [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Field-codes-TOC-Table-of-Contents-field-1f538bc4-60e6-4854-9f64-67754d78d05c?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB).

So suppose you select the whole of Chapter 1 and use the Insert tab, Links group, Bookmark button to insert a bookmark. Call it "chap1".

Then, create a new paragraph under your heading. I suggest you give it Normal style.

Use ctrl-F9 to insert a pair of the special field code braces `{ }`

Between them, type

```
TOC \o 2-2 \h \z \u \n 2-2 \b chap1
```

so you have

```
{ TOC \o 2-2 \h \z \u \n 2-2 \b chap1 }
```

Select the field, click F9 to update it, respond to the dialog, then use Alt-F9 to toggle to field results view.

The `\n 2-2` is there to stop Word displaying the page numbers.

If your styles are not actually called Heading 1, Heading 2 etc. you can specify a different style name using \t, e.g.

```
{ TOC \t "thestylename,2" \h \z \u \n 2-2 \b chap1 }
```

The "`,2`" tells Word that you want paragraphs with style name "thestylename" to be considered as level 2 entries in the ToC (without that, the `\n 2-2` will not work). A problem with this is that the "`,`" in "`,2`" needs to be the list separator that is defined in your WIndows regional settings - e.g. in some locales you would need "`;2`"

You could then insert bookmarks chap2, chap3 etc. (or whatever you want to call them), copy and paste the TOC under each chapter heading, modify the bookmark name in each TOC's field code, and update all the fields.

The main problems with this are that
 1. you don't get to specify the display text of the hyperlink
 2. you have to respond to all the prompts about TOC updates every time
    you update all the fields

I don't think there's much you can do about (2), but if you want to specify your own display texts, you could insert a `TC` field in each level 2 Heading and specify the text you want.

`TC` fields are marked as hidden so you should ensure that Hidden text is displaying before trying to enter them. But then you can

Insert field code braces `{  }` as before

Inside the braces, type, e.g.

```
TC "the display text you want" \f a \l 2 \n
```

Modify the TOC field to

```
{ TOC \l 2-2 \h \z \u \n 2-2 \b chap1 }
```

and update it. In this case, there is also an alternative to bookmarking the chapters because you can assign a different character to the TC entries for each chapter, so in chapter 1 you could use `\f a`, in chapter 2 `\f b` and so on, in both the `TC` fields and the `TOC` field, and remove the `\b chap1` etc. You can use other Unicode characters if you have more than 26 chapters.